# Dell PowerEdge R340 Error when upgrading RAM

Tags: memory

I purchase new RAM for our Dell PowerEdge R340.  I went to crucial and used their tool
https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/dell/poweredge-r340

I purchased two MTA9ASF2G72AZ-3G2R (the first one on the link above).  When I shutdown the server, remove the existing RAM, put this new ram in the same slots, I get a "Critical Memory Error" at the BIOS start up screen.

We updated the BIOS thinking it was old, but I'm still getting the same error.  I never had an issue upgrading RAM as long as I used the crucial memory finder tool.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you follow the memory population rules? https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/poweredge-r340/per340_ism_pub/system-memory-guidelines?guid=guid-5ca47374-3f83-49d6-b473-59c623b1b07a&lang=en-us

Comment: Yes.  I removed the two old 8GB memory from A1,A2, and inserted the two new 16GB memory into A1,A2 as shown on that document, but thanks for asking.  I also see in the document you linked that the newer memory speed I purchased is only supported with a newer BIOS (as I suspected) but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: I see new memory is  Rank 1, and Dell show (in diagram) 16GB memory modules to be Rank 2. So maybe the second module from your link (MTA18ADF2G72AZ-3G2R) will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the memory was defective.  We tested each chip individually, one passed, and the other failed.

We replaced the defective chip and everything works correctly now.

Comment: thats the worst... you expect the brand new stuff to just work, not give you more problems.